# VBA Selenium sometimes doesn't found an element

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I'm new using Selenium Driver in VBA and I have problems doing a click. I use ".Wait" before the ".Click" but sometimes works and sometimes not.

```
With MyBrowser
    .Wait (WaitTime)
    .FindElementByXPath("//div[text()='" + cl.Value + "']", timeout).Click
End With
```

There's any way to make a loop until the ".Click" is successfully clicked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I created a loop using "On Error GoTo" that I don't know whether is the best way but works well for me.

```
Sub WaitElements(element As String)
Retry:
    On Error GoTo Counter
        MyBrowser.FindElementByXPath("//div[text()='" + element + "']").Click
        Exit Sub
Counter:
    i = i + 1
    Debug.Print i
    If i = 10 Then 
         On Error GoTo 0
         MyBrowser.FindElementByXPath("//div[text()='" + element + "']").Click
    End If
    Resume Retry
End Sub
```

I added a counter for avoid an infinite loop. If counter reach 10 then display the error. Also I printed how many loop I got in the Immediate window using debug.print.

I hope this helps others!